# Не могу определить "GestureID" в условии "if"

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio, firemonkey, gestures

```
TListBox *setting = new TListBox (GridLayout1);
 setting->Items->LoadFromFile(GetHomePath()+"settings.txt");
if (EventInfo.GestureID == sgiLeft) {       //ошибка в этой строке
GridLayout3->Position->X=GridLayout3->Position->X-StrToInt(setting->ItemByIndex(0)->Text);
}
if (EventInfo.GestureID == sgiRight) {     //ошибка в этой строке
GridLayout3->Position->X=GridLayout3->Position->X+StrToInt(setting->ItemByIndex(0)->Text);
}
```

При компиляции под win64 все работает корректно.
При компиляции под Android вылетает ошибка:

```
[bccaarm Error] TabbedTemplate.cpp(635): use of overloaded operator '==' is ambiguous
(with operand types 'const Fmx::Types::TGestureID' and 'const System::Int8'
(aka 'const signed char')) sysmac.h(1167):
candidate function sysmac.h(1167):
candidate function sysmac.h(1167):
candidate function TabbedTemplate.cpp(635): built-in candidate operator==(int, int)
```

В чем проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: Как выглядит *полное* сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: [bccaarm Error] TabbedTemplate.cpp(635): use of overloaded operator '==' is ambiguous (with operand types 'const Fmx::Types::TGestureID' and 'const System::Int8' (aka 'const signed char'))
  sysmac.h(1167): candidate function
  sysmac.h(1167): candidate function
  sysmac.h(1167): candidate function
  TabbedTemplate.cpp(635): built-in candidate operator==(int, int)

И далее "типа последней строчки" с разными типами переменных

Comment: А из candidate function в списке названа только "built-in candidate operator==(int, int)" и больше никто?

Comment: В общем почему то оператор if  выдает ошибку. но через switch получилось все. странно!

Answer (score 1):

Если `if` не компилируется, а `switch` компилируется, то можно лишь предположить, что `TGestureID` - это некий enum для которого перегружен оператор сравнения с каким-нибудь посторонним целочисленным типом

```
enum TGestureID { A, B, C };

bool operator ==(TGestureID id, long i)
{
  return (long) id == i;
}
```

В такой ситуации получим

```
int main()
{
  TGestureID id = A;
  const signed char s = 0;

  switch (id)  // Все в порядке
  {
    case s:; 
  }

  if (id == s) // Ошибка: неоднозначная перегрузка оператора `==`
    ;
}
```

Здесь можно заставить `==` компилироваться либо через

```
  if ((int) id == s)
```

либо через

```
  if (id == (TGestureID) s)
```

Но судить о том, относится ли это к вашей ситуации, трудно, ибо информации вы практически никакой не предоставляете, а та, что вы предоставили, зачем-то обгрызена до неузнаваемости.